# Non-Jewish garden in city eruv

Tags: gentiles, eruv-chatzerot

There is a new eruv in the South Tottenham area, which covers part of the Jewish community of Stamford Hill in North East London. Most of the area is houses. Among the Halachic guidelines is [the following](https://twitter.com/ifyoutickleus/status/1271177023231328259/photo/2):

> 3. Even within the Eruv boundaries one must not carry into the gardens of non-Yiddishe neighbours, both front and back gardens.
> 4. Those whose gardens are open to non-Yiddishe neighbours either front or back should check with the Vaad what to do.

What might be the explanation for these rules? Is this something which might apply (perhaps as a stringency) to many eruvin, or is this something special to this location?

One possibility I thought of is the sechirat reshut procedure(s) with public authorities were  somehow (either unusually in this case, or because of a chumra) not good enough for private residential property. Could that make any sense? If so, could the eruv include a street which has such a garden open on to it?

Comment: Your intuition is right on. Is it normal in that neighborhood to walk into other people's yards, perhaps as a shortcut? I'm asking because I've been in other eruvin where the posek held you can't carry into non-jewish domains because of the sechirat reshut issue you mention, but he didn't publish the rule so prominently because it never comes up since no one usually goes into non-jewish domains there.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about shortcuts. In other eruvs, I have known it to be common among some people to enter non-jewish domains. For example a Jew who rents a room in a non-Jewish house or their visitor, or a Jewish apartment in a non-Jewish apartment building or student dormitory, or someone deliberately visiting a free museum or a non-Jewish home for whatever reason. I had never seen a suggestion that they should not rely on the town's sechirat reshut.

Comment: If you rent a room then you just did a schirat reshut! It's really not common to go into non Jewish homes for fun on Shabbat in most places

Comment: @DoubleAA I dont understand if schiras rshus doesnt work then you shouldnt be able to carry anywhere and if it does then even in the goys rshus. If a goy lives in a movue and uses it then without schiras rshus no one can carry and with it one can carry even in the goys rshus. It makes no difference if  his house has a mechitsa or not. Please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @interested the idea is that public roads can be rented from a government agency, but that (arguably) doesn't work to rent private land since the government (arguably) has no rights there (anymore).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109690/discussion-between-interested-and-double-aa).